# Project feature vectors into 2D plane for visualization

Tags: r, data-visualization, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I would like to project my observations which consist of more than 2 variables into a scatter plot. Some time ago I saw an R package that does this by reducing the dimensions (possibly using PCA and other algorithms) and plots similar observations close to each other. I have been googling to find how to accomplish that but haven´t found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just remembered the name of a method that does just that and its called MDS [Multidimensional scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling) which projects the data into a lower dimension while trying to preserve the distances between points.

Answer (score 2):

It sort of sounds like you are describing a [biplot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biplot).  The functions you need, [princomp](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/princomp.html) and [biplot](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/biplot.html), are both in the stats library.  You can see an example of how to use them [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/factor.html).